# celery scheduled aws upload_file timeout

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, celery, schedule

```
def upload_file_to_aws(file_name):
    """Upload a file to an S3 bucket
    :param file_name: File to upload
    :return: True if file was uploaded, else False
    """

    bucket = get_bucket()
    # If S3 object_name was not specified, use file_name

    object_name = file_name.split("/")[-1]
    # Upload the file
    s3_client = boto3.client(
        "s3",
        aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    )
    ce_logger.info(f"s3_client:{s3_client}")
    try:
        s3_client.upload_file(file_name, bucket, object_name)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.info(e)
        return False
    return True
```

When I run the above method locally, it can work normally and upload the file to s3,, but when I put this task in celery schedule, use the s3_client.upload_file(file_name, bucket, object_name) method. It will timeout. celery log is displayed

```py
[the 2022-12-08 13:40:03, 205: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1]  project.invoice.tasks.download_gmail_attachment_create_invoice[14b98680-7f38-45fb-9dbe-283330c304b0]: s3_client:<botocore.client.S3 object at 0x7f0a8a5f35e0>
[13:45:11 2022-12-08, 162: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1]  project.invoice.tasks.download_gmail_attachment_create_invoice[14b98680-7f38-45fb-9dbe-283330c304b0]:  Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "https://karbon-text.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/upload_aSZcLIM.pdf"
```

This is a scheduled task

```py
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    "download_gmail_attachment_create_invoice": {
        "task": "project.invoice.tasks.download_gmail_attachment_create_invoice",
        "schedule": crontab(minute="*/10"),
    },

}
```

```py
@shared_task
def download_gmail_attachment_create_invoice():
    file_name = get_file_name()
    upload_file_to_aws(file_name)
```

Why does this happen

I want to upload files to aws s3 successfully in the celery schedule

Comment: This seems like a networking problem. Try to connect to the instance where task runs if you can and try to perform the same operation manually and see whether it times out or not.

Comment: Yes, this is a network problem. It is caused by the problem of the agent. Thank you for your answer